# Twitter bootstrap is mobile first in IE8, how to fix?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-8, respond.js

I cannot get my Twitter Bootstrap page to get desktop styles in IE8 for some reason it keeps displaying the mobile first ones. It is fine in all later versions of IE.

There should be 3 Columns next to each other instead they are stacked on top of one another.

This is the page (http://www.skmgroupwork.com/suntrust/landingpages/307m/index.html)

I am using local hosted versions of all the files not CDNs for Bootstrap and Respond.js
I have included the suggested Meta Tag of

If anyone has any other ideas why it is not serving the Desktop styles I'm all ears. Knocking my head against the wall.

I found my respond.js was not linked to correctly but now it is and I am still having the same issue in IE8.

Comment: The issue is that CSS3 does not play nice due to @media. Have you tried CSS3 mediaquery js? https://code.google.com/p/css3-mediaqueries-js/

Comment: Terri, have you check if it is really linking the respond.js file? That link (http://www.skmgroupwork.com/suntrust/landingpages/307m/dist/js/respond.min.js) is returning 404. Also the css3-mediaqueries.js are not found. The respond.js will fix this.

Comment: @aDroidman when I follow your link to the CSS3 - mediaqueries-js the link to download them says the file is not found on the server.

Comment: @BrunoCampos I've updated my file path to respond.js (http://www.skmgroupwork.com/suntrust/landingpages/307m/dist/js/respond.js) in my file and it is not giving a 404 error anymore. However I am still getting the undesired effects in IE8. Do you think I have the wrong file? or am I implementing it incorrectly? Thanks